# php получить число с текущего url

Tags: php

url в таком виде https://mysite/news/0/2
Как поместить в одну переменную 0 а в другую 2?
количество знаков может менятся к примеру https://mysite/news/20/232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну на самом деле способов много, как вариант:

```
$url = 'https://mysite/news/20/232';
$param = explode('/', parse_url($url)["path"]);
array_shift($param);
var_dump($param);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "news"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "232"
}
```